# Google Map legends not showing on Edge and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, microsoft-edge

I have a google map application. I developed last year. I tasted again IE, Edge, Firefox, Chrome (PC and Android phones), and Safari (iPhone). It worked great. No one has complained. Then I just found out the map legend is not showing on Edge and Firefox

Here are is the snapshot of codes. I have organized the codes best I can.I have to filter the irrelevant codes.

Below screen shot indicates it is working under IE and Chrome. Safari under iPhone has similar output

[image]
Below image indicates the result in Edge. Notice all X mark. Those should be legends

[image]

Below image indicates the result in Firefox

[image]

```
var map;
var gmarkers = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33, -117), //some arbitrary values
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        initialize();
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#btnSearch", function (e){             
        google.maps.event.trigger(window, 'resize', {});
        //get latitude and logitude values
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: ''
        });
        //ajax function to get the list of address from database based on dropdowncitylist
        //traced the codes and found out addresses retrieve correctly
        //the list of addresses are stored in data variable
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.Latitude, value.Longitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            });
            gmarkers.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.close();
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
       });//end of clicking function
   });
```

Comment: perhaps you're doing something chrome specific? Have you checked the developer tools console for errors/warnings? - is there a missing `}` near the top of your code? seems initialise would never be called with the code as is - because the call to initialise is set up inside initialise, so you'd have to run initialise to add the window load handler that calls initialise

Comment: Actually, when it was developed. It was developed under IE specific. Then I tested against Edge, Chrome, Safari (iPhone), and then Firefox. No error message on console on f12 tool. Thanks

Comment: initialise  was called inside the callback google map call back function. I also moved out. Still not working.

Comment: When you say "legend" do you mean a `google.maps.Marker` with the default icon?

Comment: Yes, I mean the marker

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code, it seems there's a missing `}`. And I moved `$(document).ready(function () {` away, with this the  `initialize()` function will not be called. I set a marker value for the code to test and it runs well in all browsers, the marker will appear. You can check my demo, the result in Edge(FireFox is the same) is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWk8g.png) after I click the `#btnSearch`.

```
<script>        
    var map;
    var gmarkers = [];
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);

        function initialize() {
            var mapProp = {
                center: latlng, 
                zoom: 11,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            initialize();
        });

        $(document).on("click", "#btnSearch", function (e) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(window, 'resize', {});
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: ''
            });
            //$.each(data, function (index, value) {
                //var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.Latitude, value.Longitude);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map
                });
                gmarkers.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.close();
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
               // });
            });
        });
</script>

<body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="search" />
</body>
```

Comment: ok, thanks. Let me try moving out of document.ready and check matching {}. I will let you know. thanks

Comment: It has to be inside document ready or nothing will even show up. I check the brackets, and they all match. I suspected that could be firewall issue. i tried it running on my local machine, and marker shows up, but when deploy to the web server, it does not work. Then, why it is working on IE, Chrome, and Safari. Anyway, I can replace marker to use the image on the web server instead of using Google map.